# Сообщение об успешном заполнении формы

Tags: webforms, yii, php

Доброго времени суток. У YII есть стандартные методы для вывода ошибок формы типа **error()** и **summaryError()**. Скажите пожалуйста есть ли стандартный метод вывода сообщения об успешном заполнении формы? Например: "товар успешно создан" или "авторизация прошла успешно" и т.п.

Спасибо большое ответившим.

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('passUpdate','Пароль успешно сохранен.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Как писал [@dekameron](/users/13096/dekameron) используйте Flash.
Вот [мануал](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/)